# The view ats.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

The view ats.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I am trying to implement an authentication system, if I enter the password correctly I don't bump into any problems but when I enter it incorrectly I get this error. Does anyone know how I could solve this?

This is my view

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

This is my html

```
{% block content %}
    <form class="box" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>Ats</h1>
        {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What hapend if  your `form.is_valid()` is invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request can be a POST request, but where the `form.is_valid()` does not hold. In  that case, your view, will return `None`.

You should "unindent" the `return render(..)` part:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that here your view does *not* performs authentication. You should first check if the password (or some other token) matches. See the documentation on [**`authenticate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) for more information.

In case of a successful POST request, you should make a redirect to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging the code should work

```
def index(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this problem because you haven't written a HttpResponse object if the form is not valid.

To overcome this in your view write return an HTTP response if the form is not valid.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form, 'errors': form.errors})

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

in index.html

```
{% block content %}
    {% if errors %}
        {{ errors }}
    {% endif %}
    <form class="box" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>Ats</h1>
        {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

or you can simply handle conditions and return default request if the request is not a post request.

```
def index(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the else condition if form is not valid.

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form, 'errors': form.errors})

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

In your template you can show form errors by accessing this context variable `{{ errors }}`.

```html
{% block content %}
    {% if errors %}
        {{ errors }}
    {% endif %}
    <form class="box" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>Ats</h1>
        {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```